# Glide How to create a custom transformation with curved edges

Tags: android, canvas, graphics, transformation, android-glide

I am trying to create a custom transformation. The idea is to create a square with curved edges not fully circular, unlike [CircleCrop](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/bumptech/glide/load/resource/bitmap/CircleCrop.java).

Hope the following picture gives you an idea of what I want to draw:

[image]

Above image has two sample one with bitmap and another with placeholder drawable.

I have tried to create a `RoundEdgesTransformation` using the existing `CircleTransformation`. I have tried drawing canvas via arc, round rectangular but did not get the appropriate result as I didn't focus on computer graphics in college.

Here is my existing code:

```
class RoundEdgesTransformation : BitmapTransformation() {

    private val VERSION = 1
    private val ID = "com.app.messia.custom_view.RoundEdgesTransformation" + VERSION
    private val ID_BYTES = ID.toByteArray(Key.CHARSET)

    companion object {
        val DEFAULT_PAINT_FLAGS = Paint.DITHER_FLAG or Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG or Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG
        val DEFAULT_CANVAS_PAINT = Paint(DEFAULT_PAINT_FLAGS)
    }

    @Suppress("PrivatePropertyName")
    private val DEFAULT_BITMAP_PAINT: Paint

//    private val paint1: Paint = Paint()
//    private val paint2: Paint = Paint()
//    private val paint3: Paint = Paint()
//    private val paint4: Paint = Paint()

    init {
//        DEFAULT_CANVAS_PAINT.color = Color.GREEN

//        paint1.color = Color.RED
//        paint2.color = Color.GREEN
//        paint3.color = Color.BLUE
//        paint4.color = Color.MAGENTA

        DEFAULT_BITMAP_PAINT = Paint(DEFAULT_PAINT_FLAGS)
        DEFAULT_BITMAP_PAINT.xfermode = PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN)
    }


    override fun transform(pool: BitmapPool, inBitmap: Bitmap, destWidth: Int, destHeight: Int): Bitmap {
        val destMinEdge = Math.min(destWidth, destHeight)
        val radius = destMinEdge / 2f

        val srcWidth = inBitmap.width
        val srcHeight = inBitmap.height

        val scaleX = destMinEdge / srcWidth.toFloat()
        val scaleY = destMinEdge / srcHeight.toFloat()
        val maxScale = Math.max(scaleX, scaleY)

        val scaledWidth = maxScale * srcWidth
        val scaledHeight = maxScale * srcHeight
        val left = (destMinEdge - scaledWidth) / 2f
        val top = (destMinEdge - scaledHeight) / 2f

        val destRect = RectF(left, top, left + scaledWidth, top + scaledHeight)

        // Alpha is required for this transformation.
        val toTransform = getAlphaSafeBitmap(pool, inBitmap)

        val result = pool.get(destMinEdge, destMinEdge, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
        result.setHasAlpha(true)

//        BITMAP_DRAWABLE_LOCK.lock()
        try {
            val canvas = Canvas(result)
            // Draw a circle
//            canvas.drawCircle(radius, radius, radius, DEFAULT_CANVAS_PAINT)
//            canvas.drawRect(destRect, DEFAULT_CANVAS_PAINT)

            canvas.drawArc(destRect, -45F, 90F, true, DEFAULT_CANVAS_PAINT)
            canvas.drawArc(destRect, 45F, 90F, true, DEFAULT_CANVAS_PAINT)
            canvas.drawArc(destRect, 135F, 90F, true, DEFAULT_CANVAS_PAINT)
            canvas.drawArc(destRect, 225F, 90F, true, DEFAULT_CANVAS_PAINT)

//            canvas.drawRoundRect(destRect, radius / 2, radius, DEFAULT_CANVAS_PAINT)
            // Draw the bitmap in the circle
            // it has got SRC_IN mode
            canvas.drawBitmap(toTransform, null, destRect, DEFAULT_BITMAP_PAINT)
            clear(canvas)
        } finally {
//            BITMAP_DRAWABLE_LOCK.unlock()
        }

        if (toTransform != inBitmap) {
            pool.put(toTransform)
        }

        return result
    }

    private fun getAlphaSafeBitmap(pool: BitmapPool, bitmap: Bitmap): Bitmap {
        if (Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888 == bitmap.config) return bitmap

        val argbBitmap = pool.get(bitmap.width, bitmap.height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
        Canvas(argbBitmap).drawBitmap(bitmap, 0f /*left*/, 0f /*top*/, null /*paint*/)

        // We now own this Bitmap. It's our responsibility to replace it in the pool outside this method
        // when we're finished with it.
        return argbBitmap
    }

    // Avoids warnings in M+.
    private fun clear(canvas: Canvas) {
        canvas.setBitmap(null)
    }

    override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
        return other is RoundEdgesTransformation
    }

    override fun hashCode(): Int {
        return ID.hashCode()
    }

    override fun updateDiskCacheKey(messageDigest: MessageDigest) {
        messageDigest.update(ID_BYTES)
    }

}
```

I would be great if someone suggests me a possible way to achieve it.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but what language is this?  Rounded corners in Android is not very hard.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It's not round corners, it's round edges/sides. And the language is kotlin if you were referring to the programming language

Comment: Wasabeef's glide library has the code you need. https://github.com/wasabeef/glide-transformations/blob/master/transformations/src/main/java/jp/wasabeef/glide/transformations/RoundedCornersTransformation.java

Comment: @squeeish i have referred a little about this library but I think it doesn't have any class with something like 'Squircle' or 'RoundEdgesSquare'.BTW Let me refer again

Comment: Not exactly as it is a specific problem, i was expecting the related sample or possible suggestion from the expert in this area. Moreover, I will put the exact solution in one or two days on the basis of suggestion from the comments after creating it.